# Outlook exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

In a calendar invite I received, I entered  notes. The invite was revised. The notes disappeared. Please advise if I can retrieve. The revised invite is on my calendar and there is nothing in the deleted folder. Thx.

Comment: What version of Outlook? Is this on a corporate network?

Answer (score 0):

No, the sender of the Calendar invite is the final authority. Outlook allows you to enter details, but it can be overwritten if the sender sends an update. Since this is not a Delete and Add event, but an Update... you can't Recover Deleted Items...

Recover Deleted Items only seem to work for e-mails anyway, even though I've read that Microsoft tech support on forums seem to think differently (that you can recover Calendar revisions).

If you have System Protection on, you can try to recover to a earlier point in time of the OST, unplug your ethernet or wireless, then see if your cached OST has the calendar details. If you have a PST, this is a bit trickier, but make a backup of the current PST. There's a lot of danger in this specific advice. I don't recommend it unless you really need those calendar details.